# Fade in and out logo on header when scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll, header, css-animations, fadein

I've almost completed what I want to do but there is a glitch and wondered if anyone could see what is wrong. When I first go on the page it the CSS animation flashes.

I am trying to animate the logo and banner on my band website [Here's my website](http://www.entradatokyo.com)

I want it to fade in the small logo on the menu (".logo") once scrolled past the header banner (".slides") and fade back out with a scroll back up. Also the same but vice versa for the header banner.

Here's my javacript code now.

```
jQuery(document).on("scroll", function(){
    if
  (jQuery(document).scrollTop() > 200){
      jQuery(".logo").addClass("reveal");
    }
    else
    {
        jQuery(".logo").removeClass("reveal");
    }
});

jQuery(document).on("scroll", function(){
    if
  (jQuery(document).scrollTop() > 200){
      jQuery(".slides").removeClass("reveal");
    }
    else
    {
        jQuery(".slides").addClass("reveal");
    }
});
```

Here's the CSS code

```
.slides {
opacity: 1;
}


.logo {
opacity: 0;
}

.reveal {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-animation: reveal 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-animation: reveal 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

@-moz-keyframes reveal {
from {
    opacity: 0;
}

to {
    opacity: 1;
};
}

@-webkit-keyframes reveal {
from {
    opacity: 0;
}

to {
    opacity: 1;
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It adds the 'reveal' class to .slides when you scroll as it matches the 'else' of the if < 200 condition. This causes the flashing as the class isn't there on page load, but it added instantly on scrolling.

If you add the 'reveal' class to the .slides element in the source code (so its there when page loads) the flashing should go away.